# UML Sequence Diagram Occurrence Count

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

So I ran into a multiple-choice question about sequence diagrams, where one has to count the number of occurrences.

You will find in the attached image a diagram. The question is how many occurrences are there in the following Sequence Diagram?

In any case, in no way I of counting do I get to the desired result of 14 (12 is what I get ;) ) and I wonder which type of occurrence I may be missing.

Does anybody have the clarity to deliver a detailed analysis?

[image]

(from UML 2.5.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soo. Hopefully this will help somebody in the future. I asked around everywhere and found somebody with an explanation that fits the answer 14.

- Every execution (vertical rectangles) has a start and end occurrence. There are three executions -> 3*2 = 6
- Every message (or function call) also has *2* occurrences: A send and receive occurrence. We count 4 calls, each with a send and return -> 4 * 2 = 8
- Summing up: 6+8 = 14

Comment: About the messages, it's not a send and **return** occurence. actually each message has two MessageEnds. Each MessageEnd is an occurence. So it's more a send and **receive** occurence.

Comment: Hi @GeertBellekens. Thank you for this correction. Seems important! I corrected the answer

Comment: Seems you were right. Though, that's a pure test question which in real life will be of no value. Nobody except some tester would care about that count (and the fact that occurrences is meant as total of execution and message occurrences). Lucky me I don't have to face that in my life. If you make a dummy edit, I'd take back my down vote.

Comment: @qwerty_so Agreed - real life importance may not be great. In any case it helped me fully understand the terminology.

Comment: FWIW: Your picture is from fig. 17.2 of UML 2.5.1 on p. 569. So the wording in your test is wrong as it should read OccurenceSpecification plus ExecutionSpecification rather than just "occurence".